# Is there a way to pick a random number of elements from a list with independent probabilities in Python?

Tags: python, probability

I wish to pick a random number of elements (can be 0 too) from a list in python. The probability of choosing any element is independent of others. For example:

```
example_list = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']
example_probabilties = [6, 9, 1, 4]
```

I wish to pick out a random number of fruits, where the element 'Apple' has a probability of 6% of being chosen, 'Orange' has a 9% probability of being picked, and so on.

As far as I understand, random.choices() uses the weights differently, essentially treating the probabilities in this manner:

```
Probability of choosing 'Apple': 6/sum(example_probabilities)
Probability of choosing 'Orange': 9/sum(example_probabilities)
```

And so on...

Is there any other way I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: your probabilities don't add up to 100%, what would you expect to happen in the 80% chance of not choosing any of the options?

Comment: The probabilities of each element are independent of each other. The [6, 9, 1, 4] means that the probability of 'Apple' being picked is 6% and of it not being picked is 94%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each choice is independent of others, each should be picked independently. The main question is how to add e.g. an apple to the choices with 6% chance. This can be done by picking a random number from 0 to 1 (`random.random()`) and checking if it is less than 0.06 (i.e. 6%).

Then, the solution can be applied to the whole list:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']
percentages = [6, 9, 1, 4]
probabilities = [p / 100 for p in percentages]

results = [
    fruit
    for fruit, prob in zip(fruits, probabilities)
    if prob > random.random()
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import random


example_list = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']
example_probabilties = [6, 9, 1, 4]

choices_with_None = (random.choices([example, None], [P, 100 - P])[0] for example, P in zip(example_list, example_probabilties))
choices = [c for c in choices_with_None if c is not None]
```

Probably there is a more elegant way, but this works. Basically for each element you choose either the element or `None` by the given probability for the element and then in the next step strip of the Nones so only the chosen elements are left.

Note: With this low probabilities from the example the choices-list will in most cases (~81.3%) be empty. So to test the functionality it makes sense to choose higher probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

example_list = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']
example_probabilities = [6, 9, 1, 4]

def choose_elements(elements, probabilities, fillvalue=None, filter_empty=True,k=1):
    chosen = []
    sum_prob = sum(probabilities)
    if sum_prob < 100:
        elements += [fillvalue]
        probabilities += [100-sum_prob]
    while len(chosen) != k:
        choices = random.choices(elements,cum_weights=probabilities)
        if filter_empty:
            chosen += [c for c in choices if c is not fillvalue]
    return chosen

chosen = choose_elements(example_list,example_probabilities,k=50)
print(chosen)
```

This will give back a list of elements that has length `k`. I added some optional parameters so you can configure it for your need if you need a different `fillvalue` or if the resulting list needs to be cleared of the `fillvalue` elements.

The main difference is that it uses the `cum_weights` in the [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) which is what you need.

As @MangoNrFive said, the probability to not pick an element is `80% = (100 - (6+9+1+4))` so it can sample a bunch of times before exiting.

I also fixed a typo in the `example_probabilities` variable, it was missing an `i`.